# Typeface-roboto for what?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Given the react code bellow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import 'typeface-roboto';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const App = class extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Typography variant="h1">Hello React App!</Typography>;
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

if I comment `import 'typeface-roboto';` nothing changes in my application.

**Could someone explain me why?**

sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/x2n59kj2lq

Answer (score 1):

The package ‘typeface-roboto’ is used to import the roboto font, it includes all necessary font filesand a CSS file.It's only required when you want to change your font.And,typeface-roboto assumes that you use webpack to process CSS and file.

Comment: ok, but my point is: even if I don't import typeface-roboto, my font is displayed using it. But in the (material-ui website)[https://material-ui.com/style/typography/#general] its said the Material-UI doesn't load the roboto font. So, if this is true, which component is loading the roboto font?

Comment: import 'typeface-roboto'; means to include all the Robote font in your project and make sure you have it in your browser.But many people may already have roboto cached in their browser.

Answer (score 1):

MUI Typography component sets the font family as

```
font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
```

When you import `typeface-roboto` you make "Roboto" available to the app and the css and font files are bundled with your app.

If you comment out `import 'typeface-roboto';` then the "Roboto" font is no longer bundled and available in your app.

In the codesandbox you provided you can inspect the `h1` title and see `font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Arial,sans-serif;`

The important thing to note is that there is a very faint underline below the `Helvetica Neue` that means that the `Roboto` font is not available so `Helvetica Neue`is being used.

If you import Roboto you will see that Roboto is now underlined.

When you comment out `import 'typeface-roboto';` it may look like everything is the same in your app but this is because the fallback font in the font-stack is very similar to Roboto.

Material-ui is not loading Roboto as they say in their docs it is only made available by the import statement but unless you have a sharp eye or see which font in underlined in the font-stack you might think your looking at Roboto when in fact its Helvetica.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget that such import module type means just importing a script in es6 so which in this case is a css script for font